# `Cannot get connection` error occurs when connect to mysql in spring project

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-mvc

This error occurs occasionally while the whole function works well. But this exception can be thrown from time to time. I found one solution that copy `mysql-connector-java-5.1.24.jar` to `tomcat/lib` folder, while this error will gone. Without this, web server will eventually create too much connection to data base.

Anyone can help to explain why this occurs, and why should move jar from `webapps` to `tomcat/lib`?

```
 ### Error querying database.  Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://*:3399/*?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&allowMultiQueries=true&amp;mysqlEncoding=utf-8
### The error may exist in net/ebaolife/tpa/mapper/DivisionalCaseMapper.java (best guess)
### The error may involve net.ebaolife.tpa.mapper.DivisionalCaseMapper.selectCount
### The error occurred while executing a query
### Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://*:3399/*?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&allowMultiQueries=true&amp;mysqlEncoding=utf-8
        at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:79)
        at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:447)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy945.selectMap(Unknown Source)
        at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectMap(SqlSessionTemplate.java:183)
        at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForMap(MapperMethod.java:174)
        at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:70)
        at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:53)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy968.selectCount(Unknown Source)
        at net.ebaolife.tpa.service.impl.DivisionalCaseServiceImpl.selectCount(DivisionalCaseServiceImpl.java:329)
        at net.ebaolife.tpa.service.impl.DivisionalCaseServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$605de877.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
        at net.ebaolife.tpa.service.impl.DivisionalCaseServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e8a8ee89.selectCount(<generated>)
        at net.ebaolife.tpa.web.controller.WebSocketController$1.run(WebSocketController.java:37)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:
```

Comment: Stacktrace is the absolute minimum you should provide. With the current amount of information you have given us only a fortune teller could give you a solution.

Comment: @RafalG. attached. tks!

Comment: Do you deploy war to tomcat? This connector jar should be in classpath of the application.

Comment: It is a bit of a puzzle. You say that you deploy an application and it works most of the time, but sometimes this exception is thrown? The driver is or is not available... it should never be "sometimes available".